# Change color of navigation bar selected item

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, app-themes, android-navigation-bar

I used

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat);
```

to set my app theme darker.
Now I run into that issue that the selected item in my navigationbar is relativly dark, so that users can hardly see it.

Is there anything that I can use in my style to get the selected navigation item in another color?
Here is a picture of it

[image]

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context="at.mrminemeet.asciimoji.MainActivity">

.....


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please post xml code for activity. Are you using BottomNavigationView?

Comment: @AnuraagBaishya I added the XML now

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your BottomNavigationView:

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"       
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
```

In your drawable folder, create a file bottom_navigation_selector.xml and add this to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector 
   xmlns :android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"  android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Finally in every activity where you use this navigation bar add this line to onCreate() and onResume()

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item);
```

Comment: is it possible to make that in the style.xml as I want to make them to change with the style thats active and the user can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the **[BottomNavigationView_itemBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html#attr_BottomNavigationView_itemBackground)** attribute to your BottomNavigationView, you can set a [selector](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) as a background with different colors for the normal and selected states